# Is there a website for redirecting to odd protocols from http?

Tags: web, url, aptitude, about-config

For instance, if you click a URL with the apt: protocol in Ubuntu, it will install a package from your repository:

- Install `firefox`

As you can see, this doesn't work on StackExchange, despite the URL being there.

If you click a link with the about: protocol in Firefox, it can lead to inner workings of your browser:

- Browser configuration

As you can see, this doesn't work on StackExchange, either.  Many websites, forums, etc. only recognize http:// URLs, but there are all kinds of other useful protocols, like news:, mailto:, aim:, etc.

However, I can work around this in a sense.  Instead of linking to `apt:firefox`, I can link to http://appnr.com/install/firefox, which I know will then launch the apt: link:

- [Install `firefox`](http://appnr.com/install/firefox)

Is there a tinyurl-esque website or other workaround that allows creation of http:// URLs that then launch other arbitrary protocol URLs?

Comment: StackExchange is a productivised version of the Stack Overflow base, which is used by Super User, not the other way around.

Comment: So the software is called "Stack Overflow" and the website is also called "Stack Overflow"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just reminded myself of one possible workaround.  TinyURL itself!

http://tinyurl.com/installwine

http://tinyurl.com/aboutconfig